# Plaquette operator in Kitaev honeycomb model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spin-models, topological-order, topological-phase

In his [honeycomb model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0506438.pdf), Kitaev defines link operators
\begin{equation}
K_{jk} = \begin{cases} \sigma_j^x \sigma_k^x & \text{if }(j, k)\text{ is an }x\text{-link;}\newline
\sigma_j^x \sigma_k^y & \text{if }(j, k)\text{ is an }y\text{-link;}\newline
\sigma_j^x \sigma_k^z & \text{if }(j, k)\text{ is an }z\text{-link;}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where the $\sigma_i^\alpha$ are spin-$1/2$ operators, and plaquette operators
$$
W_P = \sigma_1^x \sigma_2^y\sigma_3^z\sigma_4^x\sigma_5^y\sigma^z_6.
$$
He writes
$$
K_{12} K_{23} K_{34} K_{45} K_{56} K_{61} = W_P,
$$
where the indices are labelled in order around a hexagonal plaquette, as shown in this image:

[image: Hexagon]

This is probably a stupid error, but I find
\begin{align}
K_{12} K_{23} K_{34} K_{45} K_{56} K_{61} =&{}  (\sigma_1^x\sigma_2^z)(\sigma_2^x\sigma_3^x)(\sigma_3^x\sigma_4^y)(\sigma_4^x\sigma_5^z)(\sigma_5^x\sigma_6^x)(\sigma_6^x\sigma_1^y)\newline
=&{}  (\sigma_1^x\sigma_1^y)(\sigma_2^z \sigma_2^x)(\sigma_3^x \sigma_3^x)(\sigma_4^y \sigma_4^x)(\sigma_5^z \sigma_5^x)(\sigma_6^x \sigma_6^x)\newline
=&{} (i\sigma_1^z)(i\sigma_2^y)(1)(-i \sigma_4^z)( i\sigma_5^y)(1)\neq W_p,
\end{align}
where I have used that $[\sigma_i^\alpha, \sigma_j^\beta]=0$ if $i\neq j$, and the Pauli matrix representation of spin-$1/2$. Clearly my calculation does not agree with the claimed identity. What has gone wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is a simple typo, and that the correct definition of the link operators is
\begin{equation}
K_{jk} = \begin{cases} \sigma_j^x \sigma_k^x & \text{if }(j, k)\text{ is an }x\text{-link;}\newline
\sigma_j^y \sigma_k^y & \text{if }(j, k)\text{ is an }y\text{-link;}\newline
\sigma_j^z \sigma_k^z & \text{if }(j, k)\text{ is an }z\text{-link.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
In this case it follows that
\begin{align}
K_{12} K_{23} K_{34} K_{45} K_{56} K_{61} =&{}  (\sigma_1^z\sigma_2^z)(\sigma_2^x\sigma_3^x)(\sigma_3^y\sigma_4^y)(\sigma_4^z\sigma_5^z)(\sigma_5^x\sigma_6^x)(\sigma_6^y\sigma_1^y)\newline
=&{}  (\sigma_1^z\sigma_1^y)(\sigma_2^z \sigma_2^x)(\sigma_3^x \sigma_3^y)(\sigma_4^y \sigma_4^z)(\sigma_5^z \sigma_5^x)(\sigma_6^x \sigma_6^y)\newline
=&{} (-i\sigma_1^x)(i\sigma_2^y)(i \sigma_3^z)(i \sigma_4^x)( i\sigma_5^y)(i \sigma_6^z)\\
 ={}& \sigma_1^x\sigma_2^y\sigma_3^z\sigma_4^x\sigma_5^y\sigma_6^z = W_p,
\end{align}
as required.